# How can I use an animated GIF on a Button-control?

Tags: c#, winforms, animated-gif

Maybe this is a stupid question, but cannot manage the next problem.
I am putting gif animation on the button. But it loops sequentially and never stops.
I need to make it stop after one lap completed.

```
Bitmap boom = new Bitmap("boom.gif");
b[ship2.Column, ship2.Row].Image = boom;
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code.

**The number of loops is stored in the image metadata.** So basically you'll need to provide a gif that has the loop disabled or [edit it with some kind of gif editor.](http://www.freewaregenius.com/remove-endless-loops-gif/)

**EDIT**

Since it's ignoring the gif metadata and looping forever, you can use http://gif-explode.com/ to get the last frame of the the gif. Then measure the mileseconds of a the animation loop and do something like this:

1. Set gif as background of the the button
2. Start a timer
3. Wait the timer to reach the amount of mileseconds for the a single animation loop
4. Replace the gif wit the image of the last frame

Comment: I've done everything as you said and if launch this gif in internet explorer, then it runs one time. But in C# it still runs forever :(

Comment: It seems that he's ignoring this metadata. I'll improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `pictureBox` and try this code (if possible to implement)

Check out the [ImageAnimator Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageanimator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
// this starts animation 
System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(pictBox.Image, OnFrameChanged);

// this stops animation
System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(pictBox.Image, OnFrameChanged);

private void OnFrameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // conditions
}
```

Comment: @user3281887 this is for picture box. In case that you would like to continue using button follow cvsguimaraes's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a series of images instead of a gif. You could use a timer and set the interval to the speed that you want. The timer will change the button's image on every tic. You will need the gif's frames for that. You can go to -> http://gif-explode.com/. Put the gif there and get each frame. Then you can put the images on an image list. I suppose you want the animation to start when the button is clicked.

```
    int i = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i == imageList1.Images.Count)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            i = 0;
        }

        button1.Image = imageList1.Images[i];
        i++;        
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
```